# Design of table structure in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have a requirement which is to keep the data of 2000 employees attendance.

So the attendance table should have design?

365 columns of each day in a year,  2000 pre-inserted records

And i will update it daily via java program

or

5 columns 2000 records daily insert for 365 days?

Or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking things. Assuming you already have an employee table with the employees' details, all you really need is a another table with the employee's ID and the date (and possibly entrance and exit times, if you care about it), where the presence of a row indicates attendance on that date and the lack of if indicates lack of attendance. You can then find this absence days by left joining on the employee table.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other details...
);

CREATE TABLE attendance (
    employee_id NOT NULL REFERENCES employee(id),
    attendance_date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY(employee_id, attendance_date)
);
```

Comment: thanks, Its a good idea though I will keep only absent records, this will have lesser data.
Is that good?

Comment: @GopalArora if you can really assume that most employees attend most of the time, and you don't need to keep track of entrance and exit times, then yes, that would be a neat trick. The only problem is when do insert records there?

Comment: Yes, I don't need timings and I will insert @EOD.